# Deserialize XML - how do I deserialize nested lists?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this XML:

```
<Response>
<Make Name="Audi">
<Model Name="A7">
<Specs>
<Spec Identifier="330025">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330026">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330027">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330028">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330008">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330038">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330024">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330019">...</Spec>
<Spec Identifier="330020">...</Spec>
```

I'm only interested in the Specs list but can't seem to deserialize it. I have tried the following:

CLass:

```
  [XmlRoot]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlArray("Specs"), XmlArrayItem("Spec")]
        public List<Spec> Results { get; set; }

        //[XmlArray("Specs"), XmlArrayItem("Spec")]
        public List<Make> Make { get; set; } 
    }


    public class Spec
    {
        [XmlAttribute("YearProductionStarts")]
        public string YearProductionStarts { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("YearProductionEnd")]
        public string YearProductionEnd { get; set; }
    }

    public class Make
    {
        public List<Model> Model { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public List<Spec> Spec { get; set; }
    }
```

and used this method to deserialize with no joy:

```
 //Deserialize responseXml to response object
            var xmLserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseGetSpec));

            using (var reader = new StringReader(responseXml))
            {
                return (ResponseGetSpec)xmLserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specs inside `Model` and also inside `Response`.  The way your XML is set up it will go inside `Model`.

You also need attributes on all your other items.

Start with something like this

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("Make")] // Use XmlElement to get multiple items without a containing XML tag
    public List<Make> Make { get; set; } 
}


public class Spec
{
    [XmlAttribute("YearProductionStarts")]
    public string YearProductionStarts { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("YearProductionEnd")]
    public string YearProductionEnd { get; set; }
}

public class Make
{
    [XmlElement("Model")]
    public List<Model> Model { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    [XmlArray("Specs"), XmlArrayItem("Spec")]
    public List<Spec> Spec { get; set; }
}
```

If that doesn't work, create an object and serialize it, then see where the differences are between that XML and the XML you're going for.